# WebStart client cannot find class

Tags: java, java-web-start

Before posting here, I have looked all over the web for an answer but the closest I have is this link http://www.coderanch.com/t/200605/JNLP-Web-Start/java/Classpath The responses there did not contain any code-specific suggestions. I would very much appreciate if you can look into my problem and suggest a solution:

I have a jnlp that has this in the resources section:

```
 <resources>
    <j2se version="1.6+"/>
    <jar href="my_client.jar"/>
    <jar href="jdatepicker-1.3.2.jar"/>
    <jar href="proweb.jar"/>
    <jar href="commons-logging-1.0.jar"/>
    <jar href="commons-discovery.jar"/>
    <jar href="axis.jar"/>
    <jar href="jaxrpc-api-osgi.jar"/>
    <jar href="javax.servlet.jar"/>
    <jar href="swingx-all-1.6.3.jar"/>
</resources>
```

At run time, using JDK8, I see the following exception in the console:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sourceforge.jdatepicker.DateModel
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at com.sun.jnlp.JNLPClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
```

I checked the MANIFEST.MF of my_client.jar (that has the main). It has the whole list of class files of my application but no jar files. Here is an abridged MANIFEST.MF

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Application-Name: My Manager
permissions: all-permissions
Caller-Allowable-Codebase: *
Codebase: http: *
Trusted-Only: true
Trusted-Library: true
Application-Library-Allowable-Codebase: *
Created-By: 1.8.0_60 (Oracle Corporation)

Name: com/its/ifc/common/client/IbcZipCode$ZipCodeDocument.class
SHA-256-Digest: QYQ5yuWWRCRZkaTkr6B2rk0sk0LW+cRJW7GyzQJsYBc=
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Have you made sure all of these jars are actually there, spelled correctly and network accessible?

Comment: Where can I check if Webstart downloaded a jar? I read somewhere that it uses a cache. I can verify that all of the jars including jdatepicker-1.3.2.jar are downloaded because the application ran fine. The JDatePicker classes, however, are not found.

Comment: Needless to say I am still unable to use JDatePicker. Can anyone help?

Comment: you can look at your webserver logs to make sure everything is actually downloaded. You can also make a minimal JDatePicker test app to verify your setup is sane in general.

Comment: No errors or exceptions in the GlassFish3 logs. I manually could download the date picker jar. I also ran a test by providing a non-existent jar in the jnlp. It immediately threw an exception. So I am pretty sure that the jdatepicker jar is getting downloaded but somehow not in the classpath.

Comment: The java console has this: CacheEntry[http://server:8080/path/jdatepicker-1.3.2.jar]: updateAvailable=true,lastModified=Thu Dec 10 14:53:24 PST 2015,length=39867

Comment: One thing you can try is to build a fat jar or at a minimum, stuff the datepicker classes in your main jar. Does your client also really need all of this other stuff, like a servlet api? Commons logging? You should be especially wary of things that mess with classloading.

Comment: Removed http in jnlp tag's codebase and used "file:///c:/eclipse/command/web". It found the jars and started up. Still the jdatepicker-1.3.2.jar is not in the classpath or so I believe because the exception is the same as above.

Comment: Built the fat jar as suggested. The classes could be found. I still think this is not a lasting solution as every time a new jar has to be used, the fat jar gets bigger and bigger.... if you could help me figure out where the problem lies, would apppreciate. Thanks

Comment: Well, the fat jar gets bigger but it would be the same size as the sum of individual jar files. A less annoying solution is to include the small set of jdatepicker classes in your main client jar. I have no idea why precisely you're seeing this problem, the one thing that comes to mind is the historical classloader hell introduced by things like commons-logging.

Comment: Actually, I thought of one easy test you can do - at the very very beginning of your main method, put something like `Class clazz = net.sourceforge.jdatepicker.DateModel.class;` and see if that specific line fails as well.

Comment: I added the code you suggested. It caused still the same exception. Fat and happy :)

Comment: Check jdatepicker-1.3.2.jar. Is inside DateModel class?